# What does caret-equals ^= operator do?

Tags: javascript, operators

I just stumbled upon a bit of code that I can't find anything about:

```
function solution(A) {

    var agg = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        agg ^= A[i];
    }

    return agg;
}
```

What does the `^=` operator do?
This code is the solution to [a problem on Codility](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingFN5RVT-XQ4/).

Comment: It's an xor assignment.

Comment: Much like `x += y` is a short way to write `x = x + y`, `x ^= y` is a short way to write `x = x ^ y`. You can find `^` in the list that this question was linked to now, it's a bitwise XOR.